# How to make the FN key work on the Apple Magic Keyboard, Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hid

FN and FN+F* doesn't works. Keys F13-F18 works, but F19 not. Google doesn't helps, as /sys/module/hid_apple not exists.

Comment: Is Ubuntu running in a VM, are you dual-booting/just running Ubuntu, or are you using the Mac keyboard with non-Mac machine?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Desktop on my PC (non-Mac) with Mac Keyboard.